# tikzpicture and background package, page bolder not black only grey

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.2cm,right=2.2cm,top=2.2cm,bottom=2.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\frenchspacing

\newcommand\HRule{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}
```

\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgColor{black}
\SetBgContents{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw [line width=1 pt,black]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (2cm,-2cm) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-2cm,2cm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center}

\textsc{\Large Proba}\[2cm]

% Title
\HRule \[0.2cm]
{ \Large \bfseries proba\ proba}\[0.2cm]

\HRule \[4cm]
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{proba}\
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{proba} \
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}

\vfill

% Bottom of the page
{\large \today}

\end{center}

\end{titlepage}
\lipsum[1-40]
\end{document}

enter code here

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Mywq67hOYlFisV9vJrl59XCM6Kg0Euud

Comment: Your code is not compileable

Comment: I'm sorry I have edited it several times and it seems I deleted something I shouldn't have. marmot corrected my fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed some errors which are most likely not your fault: every `\\[` was just a `\[`. And I added `opacity=1` to the line in the `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.2cm,right=2.2cm,top=2.2cm,bottom=2.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\frenchspacing

\newcommand\HRule{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}


\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgColor{black}
\SetBgContents{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw [line width=1 pt,black,opacity=1]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (2cm,-2cm) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-2cm,2cm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center}

\textsc{\Large Proba}\\[2cm]

% Title
\HRule \\[0.2cm]
{ \Large \bfseries proba\ proba}\\[0.2cm]

\HRule \\[4cm]
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{proba}\
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{proba} \
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}

\vfill

% Bottom of the page
{\large \today}

\end{center}

\end{titlepage}
\lipsum[1-40]
\end{document}
```

[image]